# Excel Where Two Columns From Two Worksheets Have Matching Values Grab Value From This Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Trying to find a formula, I was told a vlookup would work best I'll try to describe this as well as possible.

Two excel files.

Excel sheet 1 has the PID in column K. Excel sheet 2 has the PID in column C and the computer name in column A.

I need the PID numbers of sheet 1 and 2 to match any identical ID numbers and if the ID numbers match, I need it to grab information only information from column A (computer name) on sheet 2 and place it on column A of sheet 1.

Sorry if this is confusing, ask if you need clarification.

Answer (score 1):

VLOOKUP requires the columns to be in a specific order and for the data to be sorted, MATCH is much more flexible.

Assuming your data starts in Row 3 (both sheets), and ends in Row 10 in sheet 2, this formula should work:

=INDEX(Sheet2!A$3:A$10,MATCH(K3,Sheet2!C$3:C$10,0))

where:

1) "**Sheet2!A$3:A$10**" - this is the array of computer names

2) "**MATCH(K3,Sheet2!C$3:C$10,0)** " - this returns the row you need, for which

2.a) "**K3**" - is the PID from sheet one

2.b) "**Sheet2!C$3:C$10**" - is the array of PIDs in sheet 2 you need to find a match

2.c) "**0**" - tells it to find an exact match

The above will give you errors if there is no match, if you want to eliminate those, use this version:

=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A$3:A$10,MATCH(K4,Sheet2!C$3:C$10,0)),""),
you can replace the "" at the end with any text you want to display, like

=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A$3:A$10,MATCH(K4,Sheet2!C$3:C$10,0)),"NOT FOUND")